# Creating a custom endpoint for rest, I see the endpoint exists in the wp-json, but the request is returning 404

Tags: rest-api

I have attempted to register the route, tried all sorts of different parameters, feel my code looks like many of the examples on this site, but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
//Register REST Route
add_action('rest_api_init', 'add_advent_api');

function add_advent_api()
{
    register_rest_route('adventapi/v1', '/adventapi/', array(
        'methods' => 'WP_REST_Server::READABLE',
        'callback' => function () {
            return 'hello';
        },
        'args' => array(
            'adventyear' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'type' => 'integer',
                'description' => 'Year required',
                'minimum' => 1972,
                'maximum' => 9999,
            ),
            'adventday' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'type' => 'integer',
                'minimum' => 1,
                'maximum' => 24,
            ),
        ),
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return true;
        }
    ));
}

function advent_query(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    return 'i work';
    /*    $adventyear = $_GET['adventyear'];
    $adventday = $_GET['adventday'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'advent',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'advent_year',
                'value' => $adventyear,
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'advent_day',
                'value' => $adventday,
            ),

        ),

    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        echo 'i ahve posts';
    } else {
        echo 'No Results';
    } */
}
```

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue in your code: The HTTP method is not valid because `WP_REST_Server::READABLE` is a class *constant*, hence it should *not* be wrapped in quotes:

```php
register_rest_route( 'adventapi/v1', '/adventapi/', array(
//  'methods' => 'WP_REST_Server::READABLE', // wrong
//  'methods' => "WP_REST_Server::READABLE", // wrong
    'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,   // correct

    // ... other args.
) );
```

You should also ensure that you use the correct request/HTTP method as well as correct endpoint URL, e.g. `https://example.com/wp-json/adventapi/v1/adventapi`, when making requests to the API.

Comment: Thank you, had been staring at that for hours.